# How do you remove attached FC LUNS from CentOS 6?

Tags: centos6, scsi, fibre-channel, lun

We have a Qlogic QLE2560 HBA running on a Centos 6 server.  I am needing to remove the attached LUNS remotely.  I do not have any software from qlogic installed on the device.  Their are 2 LUNS attached to a P200 G3 SAN and I can not find anything documented for this OS on how to remove them.

```
[root@server class]# cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: AMCC     Model: 9650SE-8LP DISK  Rev: 4.10
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: WDC WD1003FBYX-0 Rev: 01.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: WDC WD1003FBYX-0 Rev: 01.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi3 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: Slimtype Model: DVD A  DL8A4SH   Rev: HP54
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi7 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T230
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi7 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 01
  Vendor: HP       Model: P2000 G3 FC      Rev: T230
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi5 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: ST3000DM001-1CH1 Rev: CC26
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 05


[root@server ~]# lsmod | grep ql
qla2xxx_conf          335368  1 
qla2xxx              1023916  0 
intermodule            37892  2 qla2xxx_conf,qla2xxx


[root@server ~]# cat /proc/scsi/qla2xxx/7 
QLogic PCI to Fibre Channel Host Adapter for QLE2560:
        Firmware version 4.06.03 , Driver version 8.02.23-fo
BIOS version 3.13
FCODE version 3.19
EFI version 2.24
Flash FW version 5.07.00 8080
ISP: ISP2532, Serial# BFD1238D93292
Request Queue = 0x63a600000, Response Queue = 0x63bff0000
Request Queue count = 4096, Response Queue count = 512
Total number of active commands = 0
Total number of interrupts = 174363060
    Device queue depth = 0x20
Number of free request entries = 1456
Number of mailbox timeouts = 0
Number of ISP aborts = 0
Number of loop resyncs = 0
Number of retries for empty slots = 0
Number of reqs in pending_q= 0, retry_q= 0, done_q= 0, scsi_retry_q= 0
Number of reqs in failover_q= 0
Host adapter:loop state = <READY>, flags = 0x185a43
Dpc flags = 0x0
MBX flags = 0x0
Link down Timeout = 030
Port down retry = 030
Login retry count = 030
Commands retried with dropped frame(s) = 0
Product ID = 0000 0000 0000 0000


SCSI Device Information:
scsi-qla0-adapter-node=20000024ff0caf40;
scsi-qla0-adapter-port=21000024ff0caf40;
scsi-qla0-target-0=217000c0ff144101;

FC Port Information:
scsi-qla0-port-0=208000c0ff144101:217000c0ff144101:010000:81;
scsi-qla0-port-1=208000c0ff144101:257000c0ff144101:010100:82;
scsi-qla0-port-2=5001438012098edf:5001438012098ede:010200:1;
scsi-qla0-port-3=50014380120999bd:50014380120999bc:010300:2;
scsi-qla0-port-4=5001438012098e8b:5001438012098e8a:010400:83;

SCSI LUN Information:
(Id:Lun)  * - indicates lun is not registered with the OS.
( 0: 0): Total reqs 6258578, Pending reqs 0, flags 0x2, Dflags 0x0, 0:0:81 00
( 0: 1): Total reqs 6825301, Pending reqs 0, flags 0x2, Dflags 0x0, 0:0:81 00
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Section 24.4 [Removing a Storage Device](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/removing_devices.html) from Red Hat's [Storage Administration Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/).

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the output of `df -h`?

In general:

```
umount the volume's mount point

# Assuming Multipath, get the drives associated with the LUN [ie sdc, sdj etc]
multipath -l <mpathalias>

# Flush the multipath device
multipath -f <mpathalias>

# Verify that the above drives are no longer used by ANYTHING
# Do this for EACH drive
lsof /dev/sdX    #Where X = drive designation above

# Delete the drives.
# Do this for EACH drive
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX/device/delete  #Where X = drive designation above

# Unmap the volume on the SAN

# Re-scan then list multipath to make sure it doesn’t find the volume
# you just removed
multipath
multipath -l
```